# M-x not working for 2 days in Emacs

Tags: emacs, binding, key, meta

I do use Emacs for years, and in particular the Cygwin Emacs version (under Windows 10) for months.

Since 2 days, `M-x` combo key is not working anymore, well `ESC x` but I don't want to be forced to use Emacs à la Vi ;-)

First, I thought that the keyboard of my laptop could have a trouble, but the same effect is observed with an external keyboard connected by USB.

Second, I though it could be due to some changes I did in my own Emacs init file, or changes inherited from MELPA. To test that, I came back into time with Git, but that wasn't it: problem still observed; to test for MELPA packages, I used a minimal Emacs (`emacs -q`) and, once again, the problem still persists.

(And `ESC x` displays that `M-x`, translated from `<escape> x`, runs the command
`execute-extended-command` -- which is expected.)

Finally, what's weird, is that the key `x` alone is working, and so does `C-x`. On the other hand, `M` (meta) is working: `M-c`, `M-w` do work like expected.

So, to sum up, only the particular combination `M-x` is not working, and I really have no idea why.

Any smart test I could do to debug this (on Win 10)?

Comment: Use `emacs -Q`, not just `emacs -q`, to get a virgin Emacs session for testing.

Comment: Specify what you mean by "not working". When you do `C-h k M-x` what happens (e.g. nothing?). Does the `Alt` + `x` combination still work normally outside of Emacs?

Comment: OK, I will use emacs -Q, and come back to you.

Comment: When typing `C-h k M-x`, Emacs "hangs", waiting for input, as it only saw `C-h k`... When typing other keys, I will only see the key bindings associated to the other keys. When typing `C-h l`, I never see `M-x` appearing in the list of typed characters.

Comment: Same behavior with `emacs -Q`: `M-x` is invisible for Emacs...

Comment: You wrote whether Alt-X worked in other apps. But I don't know how to check that in other apps. Which one would react to Alt-X, allowing to confirm whether it sees (or not) the Alt-X combo?

Comment: Dunno. I was kind of hoping that you had somehow made `Alt-x` a hotkey generally, and Emacs was thus not seeing it. But presumably in that case you would notice some other action when using it (inside or outside Emacs).

Comment: Certainly looks like Alt-X is intercepted by some other application in Windows, I had the same troubles (with other key combinations.) Check if you installed anything new over the last few days. If you can't identify it this way, try to disable start up programs one after one and see when Alt-X comes back. Sysinternals Autoruns can help with that https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.

One other thing - check if you have enabled an additional language or keyboard input method, they might get associated with keyboard shortcuts that then are difficult to get back

Comment: To make sure Alt-X is hijacked you can use any IDE if you have it installed on your computer - Eclipse, IntelliJ, Visual Studio etc. All of them allow you to associate commands with keyboard shortcuts. If Alt-X got hijacked (as I am quite certain, C-h k behavior is revealing,) then you will observe the same thing.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. @Yuri, by thinking at inoffensive soft I'd installed recently, I remembered having installed **Growl** notify for Windows. And that's the culprit!!  Quitting it, I regain M-x in Emacs. Relaunching it, I lose it again... Dunno what it does in Growl, but that was the explanation. Wanna submit a solution?

Comment: @user3341592 - yes, have posted the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sum up the answer in the comments:

If your key combination does not do what you expect - use C-h k to find out if it's a wrong mapping inside emacs, or something is grabbing this combination before emacs has a chance. If C-h k doesn't do anything in response to Alt-X - then you can be certain emacs doesn't see it at all.

If you want to confirm a key combination has been hijacked try to use some other application with it. Alt-X isn't used by regular Windows applications, but if you happen to have anything else that can have customized key bindings then try to map Alt-X to anything inside it. Eclipse, IntelliJ, Visual Studio, gvim. But seeing what happens with C-h k is a sufficient proof.

To find out what is stealing your Alt-X check what was installed or reconfigured lately. Disable startup programs if you can't recall. Additionally, from my experience a couple of nasty offenders: Intel video driver, and Windows language bar. (Not with Alt-X, with other key combinations.) Windows language bar is especially annoying when it steals C-S-) which I use for slurp.

Last thing. If you are running in a VM, your key combination may be stolen at either host or guest level (or both, as I've seen with the language bar.) So you may need to look around in both places.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem. But I found that the problem was come up with the conflict of hotkey. On my Win10 OS, M-w is conflicted with the Tencent QQ software. So when I closed the QQ or changed the QQ's hotkey, the Emacs worked well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but the problem is with Growl for windows v2.0.8. Close it and emacs will run normally.
Anyways, any new program setup could create conflicts. Stop all new (since the bug) process and check it.
(I don't want to change the keys configuration)